# Finding Active cell's column header name using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table created from List of data. How to find the header text of each column

[image: Table]

When I select the activecell's header is high lighted to orange but I want to retrieve that value using visual basic.
 I am able to find excel sheet's address but I need table's column header

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
      MsgBox Target.Value 
      MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the column header, if the passed cell is in a table

```
Function TableHeader(cl As Range) As Variant
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim strHeading As String

    Set lst = cl.ListObject

    If Not lst Is Nothing Then
        TableHeader = lst.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, cl.Column - lst.Range.Column + 1).Value
    Else
        TableHeader = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I was online searching for a good way to find the header value of any given cell in the table and after a little brainstorming came up with this working solution that I thought I would share.

```
    Target.Offset(1 - Target.Row).Value
```

In the event that your headers aren't in row 1 then change the 1 to whatever row they happen to be in.

Answer (score 2):

```
strCurrentColName = Cells(ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

If by column header you mean the cell in the first row in the same column that a change has been made then you can construct the header using Cells, ie

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    MsgBox Target.Value
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address & vbNewLine & "Column header is " & Cells(1, Target.Column)
End Sub
```

If your header was in row 2 you would use `Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column)` etc

*[Updated after comment below]*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Target.End(xlUp)
MsgBox "First value before a blank cell/top of sheet is " & rng1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: +1Thanks it is what I want but if the table is at the center of sheet it would not work !!

Comment: If your table is continuous then you could use my updated code above to find the header

Comment: Thanks but my table is not continuous but the first solution works since I made my table to appear always on top ;) :D

Comment: No probs :) If there is a way to determine the top of the table then it can be easily adapted (ie find and use a certain word "Development Region" if it is always at the top left , use a range name to "mark" the top of table etc)