# excel 2010: set RANGE.FORMULA-property with if-function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the RANGE.FORMULA property depending on the value of a condition. I need to use the IF(cond, truepart, falsepart) function for this, since the condition I am testing requires a ListObject reference. truepart and falsepart itself are again formulas.
An example prototype code follows:

```
Public Sub example()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        .Formula = "=if(TRUE, ""=1"", ""=2"")"
        .Select
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

After running example(), cell A1 shows the string "=1". I was expecting the result of the formula, which is just 1.
If I click in the editing line and press Enter, the formula is evaluated to 1, but I want to avoid that step.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comment. Based on this I changed my answer a bit. I hope I understood you right this time:

```
Public Sub example()
    For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        If rngCell.Formula Then
            rngCell.Formula = "=YourNewAndComplexFormulaHere(x, y, z)"
        Else
            rngCell.Formula = "=YourNewAndComplexFormulaHere(a, b, c)"
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Obviously I was not precise enough with my question. Actually what I need is really "a formula" as a result of the if-function. The formulae "=1" and "=2" are just minimal examples of really more complex formulae. I did not want to obscure my problem by the complexity of the real formulae. But the formula "=1" should evaluate to 1 in the cell if entered interactively. So unfortunately this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought of this solution also, but it did not lead to my desired result. The reason is that the condition, which I stated here simply as TRUE, uses a ListObject header row "label" to reference a data body range column (sorry, if I don't know the correct terminology). I have a ListColumn with a Header called [x], and I want to use [x] in the condition, e.g. [x]<3. The problem is that [x] can only be used in a Spreadsheet-Formula, not in a VBA Condition, as you suggest. Or am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: If you wish to reference a ListObject in VBA you might want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643652/finding-active-cells-column-header-name-using-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub tableColConditionalReplacement(tabName, colName)

    Set thisTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tabName)
    nCol = Application.Match(colName, thisTable.HeaderRowRange.Value, 0)

    For ii = 1 To thisTable.ListRows.Count
        Set myCell = thisTable.DataBodyRange(ii, nCol)
        If myCell.Value > 13 Then
            myCell.Value = "OMFG!"
        Else
            myCell.Value = myCell.Value + 1
        End If
    Next ii
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if this captures exactly what you want to do, but it allows you to access table column data, given only a column name. I'm sure that there are ways to make it more generic, but I'm too new to VBA to figure them out.